# Scale a Canvas so that the base64 toDataURL() is scaled as well

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm building a chrome extension to save screenshots of the webpage. I've gotten the screenshot all pieced together into an HTML5 canvas element.

If I then display the image with canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8); It works fine.

However, if I try to first scale the image by getting the context and using this:

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.scale(.75,.75);
```

and then output `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);` the image is the same size as the one without scaling. What am I missing? How can I scale the image?

Comment: This is most likely due to the fact `context.scale(.75,.75);` doesn't change `canvas.width` and `canvas.height`. Does your scaled image produce exactly the same result or does it have borders? You might want to re-draw rather than using this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a scaled down `<canvas>`:

- Create 2nd `<canvas>` width desired width and height you want to capture
- Draw 1st `<canvas>` to 2nd `<canvas>` using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images#Scaling (canvas is valid `drawImage()` source)
- Save 2nd `<canvas>`